# How to subscribe to a event from a dll file and get a list generated by the dll?

Tags: c#, events, dll

So I have a dll file that generates people and data about them. Every time something changes the dll raises an event. I need to subscribe to the event and then process the data.

I have the following information about the dll

```
namespace PeopleGenerator 
{ 
    public class RawPeopleDataEventArgs : EventArgs 
    {
        public RawPeopleDataEventArgs(List<string> peopleData) 
        {
            PeopleData = peopleData; 
        }
        public List<string> PeopleData { get; } 
    }
    public interface IPeopleGenerator 
    {
        event EventHandler<RawPeopleDataEventArgs>  PeopleDataReady; 
    }
}
```

I have also been given info about a factory I can use to get an IPeopleGenerator object

```
namespace PeopleGenerator 
{ 
    public class PeopleGeneratorFactory 
    {
        public static IPeopleGenerator CreatePeopleDataReceiver() 
    }
}
```

Now I have tried to make a subscription class

```
namespace Test
{
    class EventSubscriber
    {       
        public EventSubscriber(object o, RawPeopleDataEventArgs args)
        {
            List<string> listofpeople = args.PeopleData;
            printList(listofpeople);
        }

        void printList(List<string> print)
        {
            print.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            // More data processing to happen here
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I cant't figure out how to start generating the data from the dll. with the factory class. My thought is something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //generate a new object
    EventSubscriber sub = new EventSubscriber(????);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) can help you

Comment: Looks like you got a little lost in architecture astronautics, you never used the factory function or subscribed the event.  Do consider [an iterator instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe methods, not classes, modify your subscriber as following:

```
 namespace Test
    {
        class EventSubscriber
        {       
            public HandlePeople(object o, RawPeopleDataEventArgs args)
            {
                List<string> listofpeople = args.PeopleData;
                printList(listofpeople);
            }

            void printList(List<string> print)
            {
                print.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                // More data processing to happen here
            }
        }
    }
```

And use instance of subscriber (and its method) to handle events:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var recvr = PeopleGenerator.PeopleGeneratorFactory.CreatePeopleDataReceiver();
        var subscriber = new EventSubscriber();
        recvr.PeopleDataReady += new subscriber.Handle;

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It says I need to base an argument in the EventSubscriber
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'EventSubscriber.EventSubscriber(RawPeopleDataEventArgs )